# Best FFmpeg codec for Final Cut import

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, final-cut-pro-x

Is there an ideal *FFmpeg* codec to use when the video file is designated to be imported into *Final Cut Pro X*?

Comment: If FCP X accepts ffmpeg-encoded ProRes MOVs then that, but someone with access to FCP X should confirm.

Comment: I have I will check!

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you for the tips. You can post your comment as an answer I'll accept it!